# Playing video on HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video

I'm trying to play a video to HTML Canvas.  Am having no issues except when I attempt to hide the video source and only display canvas.  In this case I just get a 'white screen'.  If the video element isn't hidden everything works as expected.  I don't want to display the video element and the canvas element, I only want to display the canvas element that has the video feed 'streaming' to it.  Any suggestions?  Code example attached...

```js
let sourcevideo = document.getElementById("sourcevideo");
let outputcanvas = document.getElementById("outputcanvas");
let canvasctx = outputcanvas.getContext("2d");

function initCanvas() {
  outputcanvas.width = sourcevideo.videoWidth;
  outputcanvas.height = sourcevideo.videoHeight;
  console.log(outputcanvas.width, outputcanvas.height);
  drawVideo();
}

function drawVideo() {
  canvasctx.drawImage(
    sourcevideo,
    0,
    0,
    outputcanvas.width,
    outputcanvas.height
  );
  requestAnimationFrame(drawVideo);
}

sourcevideo.addEventListener("loadeddata", initCanvas);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="videocontainer">
    <video id="sourcevideo" controls src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/c/c4/Physicsworks.ogv/Physicsworks.ogv.240p.vp9.webm"></video>
  </div>
  <canvas id="outputcanvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, hide the visibility of your video container using this `$('#sourcevideo').css('visibility', 'hidden');` then you will see a still image, to prevent that use `autoplay="autoplay"`, by doing this your video element will hide also you canvas will properly run the video.

```js
let sourcevideo = document.getElementById("sourcevideo");
let outputcanvas = document.getElementById("outputcanvas");
let canvasctx = outputcanvas.getContext("2d");

function initCanvas() {
  outputcanvas.width = sourcevideo.videoWidth;
  outputcanvas.height = sourcevideo.videoHeight;
  console.log(outputcanvas.width, outputcanvas.height);
  drawVideo();
}

function drawVideo() {
  canvasctx.drawImage(
    sourcevideo,
    0,
    0,
    outputcanvas.width,
    outputcanvas.height
  );
  requestAnimationFrame(drawVideo);
}
sourcevideo.addEventListener("loadeddata", initCanvas);
sourcevideo.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <canvas id="outputcanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="videocontainer">
    <video id="sourcevideo" autoplay="autoplay" controls src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/c/c4/Physicsworks.ogv/Physicsworks.ogv.240p.vp9.webm"></video>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is really close to what I'm looking for but is there a way to get rid of the 'blank space' that is left by the video element that is now hidden?

Comment: @ArtemisJ check the updated answer now, I just moved the div

Answer (score 1):

You can set a CSS class including a style of [`display: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_none) to be applied to the `video` element (as seen in the code below, `.hidden {display:none;}`). Since the video element's class is set in the HTML, it should hide the video element but still play the video with `autoplay` on page load.

The code below shows how you can apply either `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` in distinct classes as needed (using buttons in this example).

```js
const sourcevideo = document.getElementById("sourcevideo");
const outputcanvas = document.getElementById("outputcanvas");
const canvasctx = outputcanvas.getContext("2d");

function initCanvas() {
  outputcanvas.width = sourcevideo.videoWidth;
  outputcanvas.height = sourcevideo.videoHeight;
  drawVideo();
}

function drawVideo() {
  canvasctx.drawImage(
    sourcevideo,
    0,
    0,
    outputcanvas.width,
    outputcanvas.height
  );
  requestAnimationFrame(drawVideo);
}

sourcevideo.addEventListener("loadeddata", initCanvas);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="videocontainer">
  <canvas id="outputcanvas"></canvas>
  <video id="sourcevideo" class="hidden" controls autoplay src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/c/c4/Physicsworks.ogv/Physicsworks.ogv.240p.vp9.webm"></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.  The above works when attached to buttons but it doesn't quite work (at least as I'm hoping it would) when not invoked by buttons and instead just as an event (like loadeddata).  So to expand and clarify on the desired state it would be that the only thing that is 'visible' to the end user and taking up space on the web page is the canvas element, that has had the source video 'drawn' upon it.  The closest I can come is what the other poster suggested and using style.visibility on the sourcevideo to hide it, but in this case it still leaves a blank space

Comment: Yes, the difference between `visibility: hidden` and `display:none` is that `visibility: hidden` keeps the block space where the element would be, including width and height. The `display: none` style does not. I just updated my answer to include this at the start instead of with buttons on demand.