Overlay from Image transforming in the video
How can I implement a hover effect on multiple images in my HTML code, where each image triggers a video to appear with the same width as the image? The images have different positions, and I want to maintain this while displaying the videos.
Additionally, I'm using Bootstrap 5.3 columns for layout. I also need a card layout for the videos, including title, paragraph, and an optional "Play" button with a play icon. The original image should reappear when the cursor moves away from the video.
    <!-- FILM -->
    <!-- CONTAINER FILM -->
    <div class="container-fluid text-white">
        <!-- RIGA FILM -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- COLONNA FILM -->
            <div class="col-11 fs-5 pt-3" style="margin-left: 35px;">
                <strong style="color: #fd0167;">Film</strong> / Novità
            </div>
            <!-- IMMAGINI CON I RISPETTIVI LINK -->
            <div class="col-11 d-flex justify-content-between" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 20px;">
                <a href="page3.html">
                    <img id="myImg" src="img/carousel/comedy-shot.png"
                        class="d-block" width="250" alt="Commedia" title="Clicca qui per vedere il film commedia">
                    <video id="myVideo" src="video/video.mp4"
                        style="display: none; width: 250px; position: absolute; top: 90px;"></video>
                </a>
                <a href=" page3.html"><img src="img/carousel/dramatic-shot.png" class="d-block" width="250"
                        alt="Drammatico" title="Clicca qui per vedere il film drammatico"></a>
                <a href="page3.html"><img src="img/carousel/matrix-shot.png" class="d-block" width="250" alt="Matrix"
                        title="Clicca qui per vedere il film Matrix"></a>
                <a href="page3.html"><img src="img/carousel/action-shot.png" class="d-block" width="250" alt="Azione"
                        title="Clicca qui per vedere il film Azione"></a>
                <a href="page3.html"><img src="img/carousel/starwars-shot.png" class="d-block" width="250"
                        alt="StarWars" title="Clicca qui per vedere il film Star Wars"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FINE FILM -->


You can draw your video on a canvas and place other controls on it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69819307/playing-video-on-html-canvas
